# Is there a way to introspect an array's size?

Tags: c++, arrays, introspection

In C++ given an array like this:

```
unsigned char bogus1[] = {
  0x2e, 0x2e, 0x2e, 0x2e
};
```

Is there a way to introspect bogus1 to find out is is four characters long?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  unsigned char bogus1[] = {
    0x2e, 0x2e, 0x2e, 0x2e
  };

  std::cout << sizeof(bogus1) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

emits `4`.  More generally, `sizeof(thearray)/sizeof(thearray[0])` is the number of items in the array.  However, this is a compile-time operation and can only be used where the compiler **knows** about that "number of items" (not, for example, in a function receiving the array as an argument).  For more generality, you can use `std::vector` instead of a bare array.

Comment: "a function receiving the array as an argument" - careful, that needs to be a *reference* argument. Naming an array type directly in an argument declaration causes decay to pointer type, which causes the sizeof quotient to have undesired, implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: So, if I do "std::clog << bogus1;" why can't std::clog detect the array is only four characters long and not walk off the end of the array looking for a NULL char?

Comment: WilliamKF: because that's pointless: you should just use std::string instead. The rare cases when you know the length of a string at compiletime are not worth the added complexity that you propose.

Comment: @WilliamKF, `std::clog << ...` is an example of "a function receiving the array as an argument" (by reference, as potatoswatter mentions -- specifically a const referece in this case) -- the function in question, in this case, is `operator<<(std::ostream&, const char[]&)`.  As I mentioned, it can't "introspect" the size of its argument.  Stefan is correct that you should use `std::string` for this kind of things (I mentioned `std::vector` as a more general approach, esp. when the items aren't `char`s;-).

Comment: @Alex, is that so? I believe that the array is decayed into a pointer to the first element and the actual matched signature is: `operator<<( std::ostream&, const char* )` if the function took the array by reference (constant or not) it would have to be templated in the argument array size and there would have to be a different function for dynamically allocated c-strings.

Comment: @WilliamKF: The problem is that there is no `operator<<` overload that takes an array by reference. The array decays into a pointer to the first element and that element is passed to `operator<<`. The semantics associated to that overload are those of c-strings or null terminated strings. If you really need that functionality you can use a more cumbersome approach: `std::copy( array, array+elements, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::clog))` where `elements` is the number of elements, constant or `sizeof(array)` for a char array, or `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` or some metaprogramming trick.

Comment: @David, you're right that there is no such overload in the standard library, but it's trivial to write one -- and it makes absolutely no difference to the current question's title (that overload can't introspect the size of the array it gets by const reference).

Comment: @Alex, the overload signature you declared does not take an array by reference, but a *pointer* by reference. If you really want to define a function that takes an array of 3 elements (the size is part of the type) by reference, the signature is `void foo( int (&arg)[3] )`. The syntax `void foo(int array[])` (or `void foo( int array[3])`) are exactly equivalent to `void foo( int *array )` (with the number being discarded by the compiler in the second case), and have nothing to do with arrays. If an array is passed **by reference**, which is not what your code did, you **can** inspect the size.

Comment: Consider: `typedef int (array3)[3]; void foo( array3 const & a ) { cout << sizeof(array3) << endl }`, where I have used a typedef to ease the syntax. In this particular case the argument of `foo` is in fact an array of 3 integers, and if you run the code you will printout the correct size. The important point there is: for the compiler to work on a reference which is an alias to an object, it **must** know its size. The compiler cannot possibly alias an object of unknown size (it will allow the function decaration, but not the definition).

Answer (score 4):

One thing to be careful about with `sizeof` is making sure you don't accidentally do the sizeof an array that has decayed into a pointer:

```
void bad(int a[10])
{
    cout << (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a[10];
    cout << (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])) << endl;
    bad(a);
}
```

On my 64 bit machine, this outputs:

```
10
2
```

The size computed inside `bad` is incorrect because `a` will have decayed to a pointer.  In general, don't trust the `sizeof` an array that was passed as a function argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
int bogus1_size = sizeof(bogus1) / sizeof(unsigned char);
```

Comment: I'd recommend writing that as `sizeof(bogus1) / sizeof(bogus1[0])`; that way there is no chance that you accidentally have a different types between in the definition of `bogus1` and your size computation.

Answer (score 0):

This gets around the pointer decay problem:

```
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t array_size(T(&)[N]) { return N; }
```

In that it will not compile unless the array size is known.

Comment: Yes, it seems by template usage the std::stringstream could learn of the array length and not run off the end.

Comment: @William: Possibly, but then it would almost certainly ignore any null terminators, which is unexpected when printing strings.